# Merge two Microsoft SQL Server databases together without losing data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I need to merge two Microsoft SQL Server databases. They are operational databases which have the same schema. There will be key conflicts.

For example:

Database 1, Table A:

| ID (PK) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C++ |

Database 2, Table A:

| ID (PK) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Java |
| 2 | JavaScript |

The two databases need to merge together. For the table above the output should be:

| ID (PK) | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C++ |
| 3 | Java |
| 4 | JavaScript |

The merge would have to deal with conflicting primary and foreign key values.

Our objective is to avoid having to create scripts to merge the two databases. Does anyone have any experience with this type of problem?  What was your solution? What tools did you use?

So far I've tried tools from Redgate and dbForge as well as SQL Server replication. Those tools simply overwrite the data and we end up losing data.

Comment: So you need to "merge" *tables*? What do you expect to happen if the IDs are the same but the values are different? We can't guess how you want to deal with that. `avoid having to create scripts to merge the two databases` you *have* to do that because no tool can guess what your rules are

Comment: You'll have to do it the hard way. There's **nothing** to automatically update dependent records in other tables from database 2 that have foreign key values of 1 or 2 to instead use the new 3 and 4.

Comment: To be clear, whenever there are conflicting PKs, the merge needs to re-key the records.  As per the example, the rows in the first table are inserted into the merged table but with different primary key values.  Obviously this has implications for foreign keys.

Comment: The impression I'm getting is that there are no tools that can currently do this.  We will have to create a script or scripts to achieve this manually - painful!  Anyone disagree with this conclusion?

Comment: It's not "painful", it's just going to take time for you, or the business, to define your rules. Once you have those rules then writing the solution will take a little bit as well, but a a good developer, with good knowledge of your design, should be able to get the work done in a timely period.

Comment: By "painful" I mean to say "time sink".  :-)  That's probably accurate given that we are using an ORM and the model is pretty complicated.  Any best ways of proceeding with the scripting?  Anyone with real-world experience of doing this who could share some tips?  Thanks.

Comment: MssqlMerge (sorry I am the author) has an option to use existing or to generate new identity values during import. But it can be only partial solution for tables without dependencies. For tables which are used as foreign key it will not work properly (have corresponding plans for the future but not implemented yet)

Comment: Asking for "tips" isn't what [so] is for, @user1372240 . If you want a discussion you should visit a discussion forum and ask there; [so] is a Q&A site (for *specific* programming questions).

Comment: What about building an SSIS package to handle the database merge? It might make the process a little less painful, providing you already have experience with SSIS.

Comment: We did this a lot when our customers got bought by each other. It was pretty painful and we didn't use explicit foreign keys. But basically we had some procedure that did "remap" which accepted a list of tables and columns, and from => to values. Then some central procedure that by the IDs generated new IDs for specific table, and finally some odds and ends (for example some tables got merged by UPDATEs). There also was some code that searched for column names that weren't part of the merge and warned you about, since new columns were added all the time

Comment: It's pretty easy to script a lot of the grunt work though, since you probably have same tables and column names between DBs. By checking PKs, you can figure out what should be done with the rows. The bits and ends can take some time, depending on your structure. How many tables do you have?

Comment: You will likely need to handle different tables using different rules. Databases typically have a range of data *roughly* including (1) Fixed data tied closely to the application, such as status tables. These would typically be the same between databases. (2) Configurable lookup tables that change infrequently and are often used to populate selection lists on the app. You would likely want to dedup these on merge, or somehow manage what values are available in which "realm". (3) Activity data that reflects the minute-to-minute operations. Most would remain separate. (possibly dedup later.)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments and feedback.  I've also been in contact with AWS and they have confirmed there own DMS service cannot deal with conflicts.  I'm now in the process of writing a document to cover how we will handle this.   A rough process for reference is: 1. Merge -> 2. Verify data against originals -> 3. Validate merge against software.  It's going to be complicated and time consuming but, on the other hand, a good challenge!

Comment: @user1372240 do you use identity/sequence primary keys (new values assigned by DB) or these IDs are assigned by the application?

Comment: Posted an answer to the related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869378/282694

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can try the following:

DECLARE @maxid INT;
SELECT @maxid=max(ID) FROM Database1.dbo.TableA;

INSERT INTO Database1.dbo.TableA (ID, Name)
SELECT ID + @maxid, Name FROM Database2.dbo.TableA;

Please note that this will work if Database1 and Database2 are located on the same server.